# Search contours on the image

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I'm trying solve the recognition problem with a help OpenCV library for C++.

I have a some text(below) and i want to separate each symbol in this text using by `cvFindContours(...)` function. After, I want to send each separated symbol on the input of neural network for recognition it. It's all ok. I will can get all contours in my image and i can drawn it on my image with a help `cvDrawContours(...)` function(below). But `cvFindContours(...)` returns unordered sequence(pointer on the first contour in this sequence) where contains all the found contours. For my task order is very important.

```
CVAPI(int)  cvFindContours( CvArr* image, CvMemStorage* storage, CvSeq** first_contour,
                            int header_size CV_DEFAULT(sizeof(CvContour)),
                            int mode CV_DEFAULT(CV_RETR_LIST),
                            int method CV_DEFAULT(CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE),
                            CvPoint offset CV_DEFAULT(cvPoint(0,0)));
```

`-image`- source image

`-storage`- for storing where contains contours

`-first_contour`- pointer to the first contour in the storage

`-mode`- mode of search (I use the `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` for search external contours)

`-method`- method of approximation (I'm using the `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` by default)

[image: Source image]

[image: Source image with drawn a bound rectangles]

How can I make the `cvFindContours(...)` function that returns the contours in the order in which they in the picture? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly force `findContours` to yield contours in a certain order (I mean there is no parameter to tune this in the function call).

To sort your contours in a "read text" order, you could do a loop which goes through all your contours and retrieves for each contour the top-leftest point, either by directly going through all points in each `contour` object, or by using a boundingbox (see [minAreaRect](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#minarearect) for example).
Once you have all these points, sort them from left to right and bottom to top (some adjustments will probably have to be made, like detecting all contours starting within a range of heights to be all part of the same text line)

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. It's very simple. I'm loser :D.
Thanks you! @Soltius

Answer (score 1):

You have found bounding rectangles for all the contours present in your image. Instead of going about with the **left-most** point approach, you can sort your contours based on the **centroid** of each contour, which is more robust since your approach is being for text.

[THIS ANSWER](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31515/sorting-contours-from-left-to-right-and-top-to-bottom/) from the OpenCV  community might help provide a start

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: @rekrut Have a look at [THIS](http://answers.opencv.org/question/99255/how-to-sort-contours-left-to-right-while-going-top-to-bottom/) as well